# Is this answer to the proof equivalent to the one I wrote

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

I am doing a mathematical proof in which the answer from the solution is different from what I wrote. Is the one that I wrote also valid or is it wrong?[image]

That was the answer from the solution. Now my answer:

$x^2+5x-1 = (2k)^2+5(2k)-1=4k^2+10k-1=2(2k^2+5k)-1 $

Thank you

Comment: Yes you are right. They have $-(2-1)$, which is obviously $-1$. The solution is right either way, since both outputs are odd. Still your way is correct.

Comment: @vitamind is there some kind of logic I did not use as to why their solution uses the equation I am trying to prove in the parenthesis instead of doing what I did?

Comment: Honestly.  I have no idea why they did it their way.  It's seems its just adding an unnescessary (but) harmless term.  I think your way is better.

Comment: Okay.  I think I see now  They have probable defined some form of religious ferver that an odd number is one that can be written as $2M + 1$ for an integer $M$.  Of course we could just as easily define an odd number as a number than cab be written as $2M-1$ or $2M +7$ or $2M-3$. An odd number is any integer that *isn't* even.  It's easy as a corrolary that any integer that is an odd number away for an even number is odd so it doesn't matter which we use.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your definition of an odd number.  In my opinion, both of these solutions are incomplete since they do not sufficiently define what an odd number is.

It would appear that the solution implicitly writes that an odd number $x$ can be written as $x=2k+1$ for some integer $k$.  If you were to define an odd number $x$ as $x=2k-1$ for some integer $k$ instead, your solution is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your solution is correct. If you wanted to make it a little bit cleaner, you could do something similar to the following:

Let $y = x^2+5x-1,x\in\mathbb{Z}$

$y$ is odd$\rightarrow y= $$ (2u+1) \lor (2u-1), u\in\mathbb{Z}$

$x$ is even $\rightarrow$ $x = 2k,\;k\in\mathbb{Z}$

$y=x^2+5x-1=(2k)^2+5(2k)-1=4k^2+10k-1=2(2k^2+5k)-1$

Let $u=2k^2+5k$

$k\in\mathbb{Z}$ so $u\in\mathbb{Z}$

$y=2u-1$

$\therefore y$ is odd